# Action getting no values after submiting checked rows

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Model used is shown below

```
 public class EmployeeAlconDetailsEditorViewModel
    {
        public int EMP_NO { get; set; }
        public string EMP_NAME { get; set; }
        public string EMP_ROLE_CODE { get; set; }
}



public class ListEmployeeAlconDetails
    {
        public List<EmployeeAlconDetailsEditorViewModel> listEmployee;
        public ListEmployeeAlconDetails() 
        {
            this.listEmployee = new List<EmployeeAlconDetailsEditorViewModel>();
        }
        public IEnumerable<EmployeeAlconDetailsEditorViewModel> getSelectedIds()
        {
            // Return an Enumerable containing the Id's of the selected people:
            return (from p in this.listEmployee where p.IsSelected select p).ToList();
        }


    }
```

View is shown through this controller showing table with check boxes.

```
 public ActionResult UploadAlconFile(HttpPostedFileBase UploadedFile)
        {
            if (UploadedFile != null && UploadedFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {



                List<TEMP_EMP_DETAILS_ALCON> listAdd = objTempAlcon.NewAlconDetails();
                var model = new ListEmployeeAlconDetails();
                foreach (TEMP_EMP_DETAILS_ALCON emp in listAdd)
                {
                    var alconDetails = new EmployeeAlconDetailsEditorViewModel()
                   {
                       IsSelected = true,
                       EMP_NO = emp.EMP_NO,
                       EMP_NAME = emp.EMP_NAME,

                   };
                    model.listEmployee.Add(alconDetails);
                }
                return View("AlconFileUploadView", model);
            }
            return View("AlconFileUploadView", null);
        }
```

View for displaying table.

```
@model ALCONDashboardPortal.ViewModels.ListEmployeeAlconDetails



            @using (Html.BeginForm("PopUpSubmit", "ALCON", FormMethod.Post, new { encType = "multipart/form-data"}))
            {

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" aria-hidden="true" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="modalContent">
   <table class="table table-condensed table-striped">

       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.listEmployee)
</table>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Changes" />
            </div>
```

EditorViewModel temlate

```
@model ALCONDashboardPortal.ViewModels.EmployeeAlconDetailsEditorViewModel

<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsSelected)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EMP_NO)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EMP_NAME)
    </td>
</tr>
```

Below code is action after submiting form. I am getting model object but count is 0 i.e nothing is fetched from after form submission.

```
 public ActionResult PopUpSubmit(ListEmployeeAlconDetails model)
        {
            var selectedIds = model.getSelectedIds();
            // Use the ids to retrieve the records for the selected people
            // from the database:

            // Redirect somewhere meaningful (probably to somewhere showing 
            // the results of your processing):
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: `listEmployee` is a field in your model, not a property. It has no `{ get; set; }` so the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot **set** its values.

Comment: changed it to property still not working.

Comment: You cannot just change the original question and I have rolled back your changes. Once you make it a property, your code bind the collection in the POST method.

Comment: it's not working that's why i have edited and reposted it. Why are u imposing that it will work there might be some other issue also. Apply my changes and do not mark as duplicate.

Comment: Read my first comment - `listEmployee` was a field so your code could never have worked. That was the major error with you code. If after changing that and its still not working, then its because of some code that you have not shown us (because after making those changes it will work as shown). And no, I will not remove the dupe.

Comment: I have shown all my code. If you are not able to solve it let other solve it.

Comment: FGS. I'll create a fiddle for you tomorrow to prove it. But your `EditorTemplate` only generates a control for property `IsSelected` so its a bit meaningless when you don't even submit at least some ID value so you know what you selected. And the `EmployeeAlconDetailsEditorViewModel` model you have shown does not even have a property `IsSelected` so you have not even included the correct code

Comment: Emp_no is unique id to know what is selected. And by mistake i have not  written isSelected property but as u can see it is used in editorViewModel template. It's just a copy paste mistake. This will not solve my problem. If you are not able to find solution for my problem let others solve. This is a genuine issue.

Comment: If i am implementing this without editor view template then it's working. But with editor view template still not working. Don't know the reason. Thanx for your help.

Comment: Then you have an error with you `EditorTemplate` :)